# Failed to build android project with a library project :Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest-merging

Getting this error when trying to build a project with library project.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with
>   multiple errors, see logs
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.manifest.ManifestHelperKt.mergeManifestsForApplication(ManifestHelper.kt:181)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest.doFullTaskAction(ProcessApplicationManifest.java:218)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:107)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.access$handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:64)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:51)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle(IncrementalTask.kt:134)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:476)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
>         at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
>         at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>
> ```
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```
>
> **My manifest file looks something like this**
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>
> <application
>     android:name=".TraqDataApp"
>     android:allowBackup="false"
>     android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
>     android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
>     tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory,android:allowBackup">
>     <activity android:name=".ui.activities.SettingsActivity"
>         android:label="Settings"/>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".ui.activities.LoginProcessActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
>         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
>     <activity
>         android:name=".ui.activities.ForgotPasswordActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".ui.activities.WebViewActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
>     <activity
>         android:name=".ui.activities.ChangePasswordActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
>     <activity
>         android:name=".ui.activities.HomeActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
>     <activity
>         android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
>
>     <provider
>         android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
>         android:authorities="com.traqiq.traqdata.fileprovider"
>         android:exported="false"
>         android:grantUriPermissions="true">
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
>             android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
>     </provider>
> </application>
> ```

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: In most cases, it happens when there is a reference to a file/variable/location and that specific reference value doesn't exist. Make sure the references in manifest exist in your project/directory.

Comment: @PrajwalW manifest added.

Answer (score 0):

Under application tag, you have added .App_name whereas you have created a separate activity tag for MainActivity. Why so? Do follow some tutorials online so as to learn more. Your MainActivity should in most cases be the activity which gets started when you run your app.